# If a Jew visits a fire temple and offers a prayer to "Ahura Mazda", commandments are being violated?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, avodah-zarah

If a Jew visits a fire temple and offers a prayer to "[Ahura Mazda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahura_Mazda)" as a good-will gesture, which commandments are being violated? What are the views of the Jewish Sages on this type of interfaith cross-pollination?

Comment: Who is "Ahura Mazda"?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34413/is-zoroastrianism-avodah-zarah

Comment: @PloniAlmoni, that is the Zoroastrian deity of good. Thus, there is an issur shittuf, IMO

Comment: Yes, I would say NO.